I'm having trouble fetching data with JS from PHP backend - XMLHTTP request
I have the following backend code, it is displaying the data correctly:
<?php
include ("_inc_dbvars.php");
$idu = 2; // These variables i get from $_SESSION, for simplicity I made them static.
$idm = 2; //
$result_total=0;
$result_max=0; 
$zero_count = 0; // Count of answer values that are 0
$non_zero_count = 0; // Count of answer values that are not 0
$row_count = 0;
$result_total = 0;
$result_max = 0;
$score = 0;


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from user_answer_values where user_id=:idu and module_id=:idm");
    $stmt->bindParam(':idu', $idu);
    $stmt->bindParam(':idm', $idm);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_count++;

        if ($row['answer_value'] == 0) {
            $zero_count++;
        } else {
            $non_zero_count++;
            $result_total = $result_total + $row['answer_value'];
        }

    }

    $result_max = $row_count * 5;
    $score = round(($result_total / $result_max) * 100);
    $hdi = round(($result_total / $result_max)*200);
    $reliability = round(($non_zero_count / $row_count) * 100);

    
    $color_score = "#FFF";    
    $data = array(
        "Max" => htmlspecialchars($result_max, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        "Score" => htmlspecialchars($result_total, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        "ScorePercent" => htmlspecialchars($score, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        "Reliability" => htmlspecialchars($reliability, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        "HDI" => htmlspecialchars($hdi, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
    );

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $data = array(
        "Error" => "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage()
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>

The data:
{
  "Max": "295",
  "Score": "119",
  "ScorePercent": "40",
  "Reliability": "81",
  "HDI": "81"
}

This is the JS request
let hxttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
hxttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(this.readyState);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(data);
    }
};
hxttp.open("GET", "../include/_inc_score.php", true);
hxttp.send();

The "../include/_inc_score.php" is the correct file location.
I have 7 individual modules that all need to access their scores.
I use JS to render them individually and responsively. Can't seem to get the JSON data.
Network tab from console: https://imgur.com/a/HA94SZo

Are you getting any error in the browser console? If you look at the response in the Network tab of DevTools, does it look like the correct JSON? Make sure there's nothing extra before or after the JSON.

@Barmar No errors relating to the request, only an error related to something I haven't gone around to fix. But nothing about the request.
This is what I'm getting in the Network Tab
https://imgur.com/a/HA94SZo

You should be looking in the Response tab to see the JSON.

It's the 21st century, I recommend you learn to use fetch() instead of XMLHttpRequest.

@Barmar Oh I see!
I see the response!
{"Max":"295","Score":"119","ScorePercent":"40","Reliability":"81","HDI":"81"}
But seems like it doesn't want to console.log ?

@Barmar I understand, deadline is close and I used XMLHttpRequest before.
Will make sure to move over to fetch() in the future.

If you're not getting an error from JSON.parse(), I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Are you seeing it log the readyState==4?

@Barmar Oh my god, I feel so ashamed and like a total idiot. I was in the Error section in the Console.
Thank you for the help anyway :,)

Remember kids, double check the console and see if you're looking in the correct section of the Console.
I was in the Error section and didn't even see that the data was displaying correctly.
